# using short-lived datacontext with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I currently have a long-lived datacontext in my data layer like this:

```
public class DataRepository
{
    private readonly NorthwindDatacontext db;

    public DataRepository()
    {
        db = new NorthwindDatacontext();
    }

    public void insert(Order o)
    {
        db.Oreder.InsertOnSubmit(o);
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

from what I understand it is preferred to have short-lived data context
but what I don't understand is when working with short-lived data context is how I handle the next example.

Some method on a client doing this:

```
public void AddOrderDetails(IEnumrable<OrderDetails> od, Order o)
{
     DataRepository repo = new DataRepository();

     o.OrderDeatils.AddRange(od);
     repo.Update(o);
}
```

And now my DataRepository is like that:

```
public class DataRepository
{
    public Order GetOrder(int id)
    {
        using ( var db = New NorthwindDataContext() )
        {
            db.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;
            var order = db.Oreder.Where(o => o.id == id ).SingleOrDefault();
            return order;
        }
    }

    public void Update (Order o)
    {
        using ( var db = New NorthwindDataContext() )
        {
            db.Order.Attach(o,true);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Will it update the relations ? what if some of the OrderDeatils are new (no id yet) and some are just updated. How should I handle all situations ?

Answer (score 0):

"Short lived" doesn't mean "it lives as long as the method is executed". It also can mean "the context lives at least as long as your repository".

And this seems to be the option preferred in most implementations:

```
public class DataRepository()
{
    private NorthwindContext _context;

    public DataRepository( NorthwindContext context )
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public Order GetOrder( int id )
    {
        return this._context.....
    }
```

Note that by injecting the context into the repository, rather than creating a context instance per repository, you not only have the same context in all repository methods but also you can share the same instance of the context **between** different repositories.

Comment: Hey Wiktor, thanks for your answer. But, keeping references to the context from multiple repositories wouldn't result of it being bloated with data and use a high memory consumption ?

Comment: No. You usually don't let your context live longer than a single HTTP request (web) or a single form (desktop). What **is** important, however, is the ability to control the lifetime in an explicit way. In your original approach, there is no control (or rather, you let your contexts live too short).